# Loops with foreach statement

Tags: php, html, sql, joomla

I'm currently managing the display of MySQL content in HTML with foreach loop like this :

```
<?php
  echo "<table class=\"tableau\">
        <tr bgcolor=\"#a72333\" class=\"first\">
            <th>Repere</th>
            <th>Niveau</th>
            <th>Enseigne</th>
            <th>Activités</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>";

$db= JFactory::getDBO();
$query = 'SELECT baseData, sid, fid FROM XXXX_sobipro_field_data';
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$j = 0;
foreach ($results as &$value) {
    if ($value->sid == 55) {
        if ($value->fid == 20) {
            $repere = $value->baseData; 
        }
        if ($value->fid == 16) {
            $level = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 22) {
            $title = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 17) {
            $activity = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 21) {
            $display = $value->baseData;
        }
    if ($value->sid == 56) {
        if ($value->fid == 20) {
            $repere1 = $value->baseData; 
        }
        if ($value->fid == 16) {
            $level1 = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 22) {
            $title1 = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 17) {
            $activity1 = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 21) {
            $display1 = $value->baseData; // <- Here it's $display_NUM where _NUM = 1. It goes on and on until 24 for now.
        }
    }
[...]
 // It ends at if ($value->fid == 83) but It could be more , it's not always the same ID
}
```

So I name my variable like this `$title_NUM`, `$activity_NUM`, ..., where `_NUM` is a number starting at "nothing", it ends at 24 for now, but it could be more if I have more data in my table.

After I get the data I display the html like this :

```
if ($display == 1) {
    echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#eaeaeb\">
        <td valign=\"top\">".$j"</td>
        <td align=\"top\">".$level."</td>
        <td valign=\"top\"><a data-lightbox=\"width:600;type:iframe;\" href=\"LINK\">".$title."</a></td>
        <td align=\"top\">".$activity."</td>
    </tr>";
    $repere = $j;
    $j++;
}
```

And the same happens here I'm displaying each linke of the html "by hand" , O don't have any loop to do the job.

Is there a way to do the job with only loops ?

**EDIT 2**

I already tried something like this :

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach ($results as&$value) {
  while (i <= 83) {
    if ($value->sid == $i) {
        if ($value->fid == 20) {
            $repere[$j] = $value->baseData; 
        }
        if ($value->fid == 16) {
            $level[$j] = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 22) {
            $title[$j] = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 17) {
            $activity[$j] = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 21) {
            $display[$j] = $value->baseData;
        }
      $j += 1;
   }
  $i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any variables named `$title_NUM`, `$activity_NUM`, etc.  Am I missing something?  Shouldn't those be an array instead?  Arrays tend to work better when you need to iterate over data.

Comment: What you need sorry?

Comment: Still unclear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use arrays for variables you need to loop. So, instead of using:

```
$display, $display1, $display2, ....
$activity, $activity1, $activity2, ....
```

Define arrays, one- or two-dimensional, which would be better in your case:

```
$output = array();
$check_sids = array(55, 56); /* Edit this list... */
```

than something similar to...

```
foreach ($results as &$value) {
    if (in_array($value->sid, $check_sids)) {
        $add = array(
            'repere' => ($value->fid == 20) ? $value->baseData : '',
            'level' => ($value->fid == 16) ? $value->baseData : '',
            'title' => ($value->fid == 22) ? $value->baseData : '',
            'activity' => ($value->fid == 17) ? $value->baseData : '',
            'display' => ($value->fid == 21) ? $value->baseData : ''
        );
        $output[] = $add;
    };
};
```

After that it would be easy to output html by looping the `$output`.

Comment: is there a way I don't need to fill the $check_sids array ? WOuld be more easy, and I could add id just on the admin side and not on the code side

Comment: But thanks i'm trying this right now :) Can you help me on the html output also ? Thnaks

Comment: It doesn't work if i print $output['55'] it's empty Array ( [repere] => [level] => [title] => [activity] => [display] => 0 )

Comment: This answer is just an idea to help you go on using arrays instead of bunch of variables. I have no idea of what you have on admin side. It looks to me that you have enough skills to debug the script, it should not be hard.